# Rails group/having/count query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a situation like: `Company` has_many `Users`

To get the Companies that have 3 Users, this works efficiently:

```
Company.joins(:users).group("companies.id").having("COUNT(users.id)=3")
```

But what's the most efficient way to get the Companies that have 0 Users (none)? Because, obviously, the same approach would not work (as `joins` by definition excludes Companies with 0 Users):

```
Company.joins(:users).group("companies.id").having("COUNT(users.id)=0")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

```
Company.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON companies.id = users.company_id')
```

Comment: I think this could be simplified by using 'includes' instead of 'joins'. Like: Company.includes(:users).group("companies.id").having("COUNT(users.id)=0")

Comment: @miguelfg : That was my initial thought as well. But no, this does not work. The error you get with this is: `Unknown column 'users.id' in 'having clause'`

Answer (score 1):

As Rails continues to develop, this can now also be formulated without explicit SQL.
Also, searching companies without users is easier with an outer join and a where on null user.id:

```
Company.left_outer_joins(:users).where(users: {id: nil})
```